# Does $(a,a]$ equal $a$?

Tags: notation, convention

In one of my exercises, I had a statement of the form $\forall x \in (c,b]: \varphi(x)$. However, it was possible that $c$ could take on the value of $b$...in which case, $(c,b]=(b,b]$.

Is it safe to say that $(b,b] = b$? Or do I need to reword my initial statement to $\big(\forall x \in (c,b): \varphi (x) \big) \land \varphi(b)$

In the event that it matters, this exercise takes place within the context of $\mathbb R$.

---

Edit:

As the comments suggest...

$S_{\mathbb R}=(b, b] \iff S_{\mathbb R}=\{x \in \mathbb R: x \gt b \text{ and } x \leq b\}$. No such $x$ satisfies this. So $S_{\mathbb R} = \emptyset$.

Comment: $(b,b]$ is empty https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Note_on_conflicting_terminology.

Comment: I think (a, a] should stand for an empty set. Left ( indicates that the set should be open, which the only subset of {a} that is open is an empty set

Comment: @markvs so I need to reword the statement as I did in the post?

Comment: Yes, if that was what you meant.

Comment: Technically, (b,b] makes sense, the set of $x$ for which $b<x\le b$ holds. Of course, no $x$ can satisfy this since we would get $b<b$. Therefore it is clearly the empty set. It is however rather strange to include and exclude $b$ at the same time , hence it is debatable whether we should not rather use $(b,b)$ which is also the empty set , but without this issue.